# Get the number of files that match a pattern in a directory and delete the oldest one

Tags: wildcards, ksh

I'd like to do the following:

1. Get the number of files in a given directory that match a given pattern, for example:

   `ExtractBackup_{date}.tar.gz`
2. If that number is 2 or higher, delete the oldest file which matches that pattern.

How do I go about doing this using a Korn Shell (`.ksh`) script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to count files matching a pattern, but you can do it in two easy steps: generate the list of files, and take the length of the list. Assuming the date is in YYYYMMDD form (note that this clobbers the positional parameters):

```
set ExtractBackup_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].tar.gz
if [ -e "$1" ]; then count=$#; else count=0; fi
```

In ksh93, you can make the count easier by making the list be empty if no file matches. Portably, a pattern that doesn't match any file is replaced by a list containing one word which is the pattern itself; ksh93 has a construct to have the pattern expand to an empty list instead. Ksh has arrays, which means you don't need to clobber the positional parameters.

```
backups=(~(N:ExtractBackup_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].tar.gz))
count=${#backups[@]}
```

If the date is in YYYYMMDD form, then the oldest file is the first in the list.

```
set ExtractBackup_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].tar.gz
if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then rm "$1"; fi
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thanks!  My date was in YYYYMMDDhhmmss format so I had to tweak it but only slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, run this script with the pattern as the argument and if more than one files matches it will delete the oldest, for example:

```
$ ksh dtof.sh ?? # this will delete the oldest two-character file
```

The script:

```
for i in "$@"; do
  if [ ! "$oldest" ]; then
    oldest="$i"
    continue
  fi
  if [ "$i" -ot "$oldest" ]; then
    oldest="$i"
    reap="$i"
  else
    reap="$oldest"
  fi
done
[ "$reap" ] && rm "$reap"
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about ksh so I'll give you some tools that you can put together.

Find all files in current folder that match a certain pattern, and return the count

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.tgz' | wc -l
```

To select the oldest file, select the first entry from the output below

```
ls -t1p | grep -v /
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is [generally not recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), though it works here since the file names are tame. `find` isn't the right tool as recursion into directories isn't wanted.

Comment: How about rounding out this answer by showing how to read the first command into a variable, then making sure the variable is >= 2 before running a delete on all but the latest?